# Solving a simple non-linear equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, solver

I have the following problem:

```
y=5;
syms x;
z = 1:5;
solve(exp(x*max(z))/sum(exp(x*z))-y,x)
```

The output I get is:

z = 1:5;

```
Warning: The solutions are parametrized by the symbols:
z1 = {0.08428351324821874240165938567037 -
2.5448937468890335808057943875982*I, 0.027288262408886135481488159484547
- 1.2999621981120554573735787663938*I,
0.08428351324821874240165938567037 +
2.5448937468890335808057943875982*I, 0.027288262408886135481488159484547
+ 1.2999621981120554573735787663938*I}

> In solve at 94
ans =
z1
```

However, I need a numeric solution. Could anyone recommend a noob-friendly approach?

Thanks!
 (Thanks @horchler for helping me rephrase the question)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `x` is a symbolic variable, while the vector `z` is numeric? So, something like this:

```
syms x y;
z = 1:5;
solve(exp(x*max(z))/sum(exp(x*z))==y,x)
```

which returns

```
Warning: The solutions are parametrized by the symbols:
z1 = RootOf(y*z^4 - z^4 + y*z^3 + y*z^2 + y*z + y, z)

> In solve at 180 

ans =

    log(z1)
```

`solve` does give you a solution, just not an explicit one. It tells you that you have several solutions that are the roots of some polynomial. The more elements that `z` has (and depending on the specific values of `z`) the higher the order the polynomial will be. The roots of quadratics and cubics are easily found. Quartics (with constant coefficients) can also be factored. Some quintics can be too, but for higher orders, there are very few known analytical solutions for the roots. You'll likely need to use numeric techniques to obtain solutions.

**EDIT**:
For your equation you might try a substitution: let `xp = exp(x)`. Then your version of `solve` might have an easier time. So:

```
syms xp;
y = 5;
z = 1:5;
log(solve(xp^max(z)/sum(xp.^z)==y,xp))
```

which returns

```
ans =

    0.027288262408886135481488159484547 - 1.2999621981120554573735787663938*i
    0.027288262408886135481488159484547 + 1.2999621981120554573735787663938*i
    0.08428351324821874240165938567037 - 2.5448937468890335808057943875982*i
    0.08428351324821874240165938567037 + 2.5448937468890335808057943875982*i
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Horchler!

x is a numeric variable. Here is exactly what I need:

>> y=5;
>> syms x;
z = 1:5;
solve(exp(x*max(z))/sum(exp(x*z))-y,x)

This returns the following: 
Warning: The solutions are parametrized by the symbols:
z1 = {0.08428351324821874240165938567037 -
2.5448937468890335808057943875982*I, 0.027288262408886135481488159484547
..............
 
> In solve at 94
ans =
z1

Could you recommend a numeric solution since I will need higher orders?

Comment: @SimbatSeaman: Are you sure? if `y` is a numeric constant too this is a lot easier. On R2012b I directly get a single complex numeric root if I enter what you wrote: `0.027288262408886135481488159484547 - 1.2999621981120554573735787663938*i`. If I add the `'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints'` parameter and set it to `true` I get two pairs of complex conjugate solutions (no idea if that is all of the solutions). What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: Also, you say 'x' is numeric and then you create it as a symbolic variable?

Comment: If `solve` doesn't work out, as far as finding complex roots of nonlinear equations goes, there's not much directly built into Matlab as far as I know. You'll need to break the problems into real and imaginary parts and use `fsolve` or a least squares solver. Try Googling "matlab find complex roots" and you'll see some questions at Matlab Central that might be of help.

Comment: I have v R2011a, may be that is why we get somewhat different solutions. A bit earlier I was able to find a solution which works well for me and I will post as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a decent solution myself using the fzero function:

```
>> f=@(x,y,z)exp(x*max(z))/sum(exp(x*z))-y;
    z=-0.1:0.005:0.015;
    y=0.52;
    x=fzero(@(x) f(x,y,z),50)
x =
  146.7938
```

Comment: That's the only real solution for that set of parameters -is that what you want? There are also eleven pairs of complex conjugates according to `solve`. Other combinations may have multiple real roots.

Comment: Yeah, this is just what I was looking for. I guess 'solve' was the wrong place to start.